# Pasting after ClearContents in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I am trying to copy data from a table into another sheet.

```vb
Sub ListOfSquads()
  
    Sheets("Apontamentos").Select
    Range("Apontamentos[[#Headers],[Área]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Squads").Select
        
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Squads").Columns("A:A").ClearContents
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Squads").Range("A1").Select
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Squads").Paste
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The `ClearContents` command is making a

> Run-Time error '1004'> Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: What about running the ClearContents before copying the data?

Comment: Search this site for the exact error message you're getting (*run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error*). This question has been asked and answered here many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Excel Table Column (`ListColumn.Range`)

- In your code, when you did the `ClearContents`, you actually removed the copied range from the clipboard. As Tim Williams suggested in the comments, you had to move the `ClearContents` line before the `Selection.Copy` line and appropriately rearrange the `Select` lines.
- Using `Select` is a `Macro Recorder` 'thing' and is best avoided in your code, as described
  in this [`legendary post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1).
- This code uses the [`Range.Copy method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ListOfSquads()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Apontamentos")
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = sws.ListObjects("Apontamentos")
    Dim slcl As ListColumn: Set slcl = stbl.ListColumns("Área")
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slcl.Range
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Squads")
    dws.Columns("A").ClearContents
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy
    scrg.Copy dfCell
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I went through the post that you mentioned but I couldn't really understand it :( But your example made it clearer. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: This code doesn't use `Select`. When you run it whatever you have active or selected, 
stays active and selected. When you use `Select` or `Activate`, the selection changes, it 'jumps' from sheet to sheet, from range to range... thus slowing down your code. For this particular case, it is enough to study this code. For a wider understanding, study the accepted answer in the suggested link.